# AWS S3 - How to fix 'Request Signature Does Not Match' & Signed URL x-amz-security-token

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am encountering an issue with retrieving files from S3 through my lambda function with the `GetPresignedUrl()` method.

```xml
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
  <AWSAccessKeyId>{Key}</AWSAccessKeyId>
  <StringToSign>GET x-amz-security-token: {pathtofile.pdf}</StringToSign>
  <SignatureProvided></SignatureProvided>
  <StringToSignBytes></StringToSignBytes>
  <RequestId></RequestId>
  <HostId></HostId>
</Error>
```

Using the `AmazonS3Client.GetPresignedURL()` returned a url with request signature does not match error. However, the same method works normally when running the program **locally** (I was able to download the file).

I have ensured that the Lambda role has the necessary permission to the S3 bucket. After deployment I am seeing `x-amz-security-token` being included by the request URL on the lambda App. This was not present upon local development. I understand with Lambda using temporary credentials for the application, which is why the `x-amz-security-token` is generated, I think.

Note that I have no issues with uploading the file to S3, and verified the key that was used to save and get points to the same object.

**Upload File**

```cs
        public async Task<string> SaveFileAsync(IFormFile file, string key) {
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest {
                BucketName = _amazonConfig.S3BucketName,
                Key = key,
                InputStream = stream,
            };
            await AmazonS3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
            stream.Dispose();

            return GetResourceUrl(key);
        }
```

**Download File**

```cs
        public string GetFileURL(string key, int expireAfter) {
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest {
                BucketName = _amazonConfig.S3BucketName,
                Key = key,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expireAfter)
            };
            string path = AmazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
            return path;
        }
```